# Post a Tweet with twitter4j

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I have a twiiter app with:

// Bearer token

// API key

// API key secret

// Access token:

// Access token secret:

and `Read, Write, and Direct Messages`  permissions

I use a ConfigurationBuilder class to configure Twitter4J programmatically in Java:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setOAuthConsumerKey("IX9qalH5azhSk61ZoFMiL83Jg")   // API key
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret("tidoT2GgVZE3B3txDb64tuinlv0wZHbKesX5bNIcjPWpxmcYcs") // API key secret
            .setOAuthAccessToken("1345093646195010258-goY3W4oyqSltGFSUNPwJy8pSjSmfI5") // Access token:
            .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("ijkpYB8sacVcBdvKHOnh95Y3QRITzD3c4Uq8nUUMLTN8O"); //Access token secret:
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    return tf.getInstance();
```

But I have this error when I try to publish:

```
401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.
{"request":"\/1.1\/media\/upload.json","error":"Read-only application cannot POST."}
```

I send the tweets from an Ubuntu server , already sync (https://vitux.com/how-to-sync-system-time-with-internet-time-servers-on-ubuntu-20-04/)

```
root@localhost:~# timedatectl
               Local time: Wed 2021-01-06 08:03:11 UTC
           Universal time: Wed 2021-01-06 08:03:11 UTC
                 RTC time: Wed 2021-01-06 08:03:12    
                Time zone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)       
System clock synchronized: yes                        
              NTP service: active                     
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From this response below, I think you are using [this API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload).

```
401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.
{"request":"\/1.1\/media\/upload.json","error":"Read-only application cannot POST."}
```

As there is an error message like below you need to create a Twitter application with Read & Write permissions. For more details about error messages, [check this](https://developer.twitter.com/en/support/twitter-api/error-troubleshooting#http-status-codes).

> Read-only application cannot POST.

Here is the official developer document about [app permissions](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/apps/app-permissions).
Change this:
[image: Read only app]
to this:
[image: Read and write app]

I hope, this is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid consumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock is in sync.
{"request":"\/1.1\/media\/upload.json","error":"Read-only application cannot POST."}
```

As there is an error message like below you need to create a Twitter application with Read & Write permissions. For more details about error messages, check this.